# How to create file upload with Rails Devise user edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, paperclip, simple-form

Is there a way to create file upload (picture_id) with `Rails Devise` on editing user profile?

Also my user `picture_id` belongs_to `uploaded_file` model. Is there a way to include file upload, process the file, save the file, add a new row for `uploaded_files` table then reference this with foreign key on `users` table?

I'm also using `Paperclip` and `Simpleform` gems.

Comment: Can you provide your current code setup for your controllers & models?

Comment: I thought paperclip did this anyway. With paperclip you should create a column in your user.rb table with the :picture.

Answer (score 0):

Paperclip gives you the option to add a picture or avatar to a column, I believe the related option is under migrations

```
rails generate paperclip user avatar
```

The instructions can be found on the github:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

Not sure I fully understand the question, but this is what I think you need in order to solve the problem.